# A lot of prepared modals or one modal + ajax requests?

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, loading, html

I'm building a web app using Yii2 (php, mysql).  Users can click on others' game results to see what item the user used for this result.  There can be from 100 to 1000 results displayed on a single page. I don't know which option is the best in terms of speed for the page and the server :

1- On page load, a modal is loaded for every result and displayed when users click on a result.  This way, there can be from 100 to 1000 modal loaded on the page. Is this too heavy considering that only a few of them will be used?  Or even none of them sometimes.

2 - Load only one modal that is brought up when users click on any results and dynamically adjust his content using an ajax request to the server depending on which results was clicked.  This way, less code loaded on the page but more requests to the server.

First option is easier to code but I think the second one might be better for page load.  I'm far from expert in terms of page size and server requests handling, so I'd like to get some opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've answered the question yourself.

The second option is right. Only one modal (per type of action -- edit, view, etc) should exist. Then use ajax to load data only when requested.

Your users will thank you. The page size and load times will be significantly better.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  My lack of experience suggested to confirm with others.  Thanks.